# How to detect the screen resolution with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, screen-resolution

Is there a way that works for all browsers?

Answer (score 404, accepted):

*original answer*

Yes.

```
window.screen.availHeight
window.screen.availWidth
```

*update* 2017-11-10

From [Tsunamis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1584876/tsunamis) in the comments:

> To get the native resolution of i.e. a mobile device you have to multiply with the device pixel ratio: `window.screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio` and `window.screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio`. This will also work on desktops, which will have a ratio of 1.

And from [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3513171/ben) in another answer:

> In vanilla JavaScript, this will give you the AVAILABLE width/height:
>
> ```
> window.screen.availHeight
> window.screen.availWidth
> ```
>
> For the absolute width/height, use:
>
> ```
> window.screen.height
> window.screen.width
> ```

Comment: It's not quite correct now. It does not consider possible changing of page zoom.

Comment: @sergzach - In that case I would use jQuery's `$(window).width()` instead, see chaim.dev's answer

Comment: When i'm using this i'm getting a smaller screen size than i actually have, and i need it precisely. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use window.screen.height and window.screen.width to get the exact screen size (as suggested in the next answer). The reason you are not getting the exact size is that it's checking the available width and height, this means that it will subtract the toolbar height (which is exactly 40px on windows 7/8)

Comment: Wouldn't be better, for screen resolution to go with window.screen.height and width? why availHeight? my availWidth for instance, is returning 1050, when its actually 1080.

Comment: @Malavos; you're probably right.  It's been a long time since I posted this, and I'm not sure why I suggested avail*

Comment: @JohnWeldon It's okay, you cleary know what you are talking about here in SO, just wanted to know because I went to this question here yesterday, while researching. I suggested a edit.

Comment: @sergzach And how possible zoom of **page** would change dimensions of **screen**? The OP is asking about size of screen, not browser window or page dimensions. The answer is perfectly correct.

Comment: Here is a helpful tutorial -- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp

Comment: This does not give me device pixels on iPad mini 4

Comment: @eckes you have to multiply with `window.devicePixelRatio`. Refer to my comment on Alessandros answer.

Comment: @Malavos the difference between 1080 and 1050 is 30 that is probably the vertical scrollbar width.

Comment: @Frank wow, this comment is old! But thanks anyway. I imaginated that some time later from when I made the comment. Thanks for the input anyway. This question is very useful for newcomers to JS.

Comment: This might be the correct answer for many purposes, but it is important to note that this doesn't always give you the *physical* resolution (even when using devicePixelRatio). On my MacBook, if I change my display settings from 1440x900 to 1280x800 the devicePixelRatio stays the same (2), even though a full screen browser window reports a window.width() of 1440 before and 1280 after. The calculation given would yield 2880 at first and then 2560, and obviously the screen is not physically changing. (I'm not sure how to get the physical resolution at this point.)

Comment: I found (2 - window.devicePixelRatio) * window.screen.width more useful to me.

Answer (score 59):

```
var width = screen.width;
var height = screen.height;
```

Comment: This is equivalent of `window.screen`. Should just add it to the existing answer.

Comment: Actually this is the correct answer. `screen.availHeight` just gives the available height in the browser window while `screen.height` gives the exact height of the screen.

Comment: This returns the dpi scaled resolution, not the native screen resolution.

Comment: To get the native resolution of i.e. a mobile device you have to multiply with the device pixel ratio: `window.screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio` and `window.screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio`. This will also work on desktops, which will have a ratio of 1.

Comment: Desktop computers won't necessarily have a ratio of 1.

Answer (score 43):

In vanilla JavaScript, this will give you the ***AVAILABLE*** width/height:

```
window.screen.availHeight
window.screen.availWidth
```

For the absolute width/height, use:

```
window.screen.height
window.screen.width
```

Both of the above can be written without the window prefix.

Like jQuery? This works in all browsers, but each browser gives different values.

```
$(window).width()
$(window).height()
```

Answer (score 30):

You can also get the WINDOW width and height, avoiding browser toolbars and... (not just screen size).

To do this, use:
`window.innerWidth`  and  `window.innerHeight` properties. [See it at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp).

In most cases it will be the best way, in example, to display a perfectly centred floating modal dialog. It allows you to calculate positions on window, no matter which resolution orientation or window size is using the browser.

Comment: This is the most useful solution.  The window.screen.availWidth property gives the SCREEN, not the viewport, which may be different. It's more useful to me to know how much real estate I can actually use, not what the browser's max might be/become.

Comment: the only correct answer

Answer (score 23):

Do you mean display resolution (eg 72 dots per inch) or pixel dimensions (browser window is currently 1000 x 800 pixels)?

Screen resolution enables you to know how thick a 10 pixel line will be in inches. Pixel dimensions tell you what percentage of the available screen height will be taken up by a 10 pixel wide horizontal line.

There's no way to know the display resolution just from Javascript since the computer itself usually doesn't know the actual dimensions of the screen, just the number of pixels. 72 dpi is the usual guess....

Note that there's a lot of confusion about display resolution, often people use the term instead of pixel resolution, but the two are quite different. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution)

Of course, you can also measure resolution in dots per cm. There is also the obscure subject of non-square dots. But I digress.

Answer (score 18):

Using jQuery you can do:

```
$(window).width()
$(window).height()
```

Comment: Tis the easiest cross/everything solution I've used. For browser width at least...

Comment: This returns the window's size, not the screen resolution.

Answer (score 13):

Trying to get this on a mobile device requires a few more steps. `screen.availWidth` stays the same regardless of the orientation of the device.

Here is my solution for mobile:

```
function getOrientation(){
    return Math.abs(window.orientation) - 90 == 0 ? "landscape" : "portrait";
};
function getMobileWidth(){
    return getOrientation() == "landscape" ? screen.availHeight : screen.availWidth;
};
function getMobileHeight(){
    return getOrientation() == "landscape" ? screen.availWidth : screen.availHeight;
};
```

Comment: `window.orientation` returns undefined... (Firefox 49) `screen.orientation.angle` returns an angle, but it's already at 0 for landscape mode.

Answer (score 7):

See [Get Monitor Screen Resolution with Javascript](http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/browser-screen-resolution/) and the [`window.screen` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.screen)

Answer (score 4):

```
function getScreenWidth()
{
   var de = document.body.parentNode;
   var db = document.body;
   if(window.opera)return db.clientWidth;
   if (document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat') return de.clientWidth;
   else return db.clientWidth;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

just for future reference:

```
function getscreenresolution()
{
    window.alert("Your screen resolution is: " + screen.height + 'x' + screen.width);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to detect screen resolution, you might want to checkout the plugin [res](https://github.com/ryanve/res). It allows you to do the following:

```
var res = require('res')
res.dppx() // 1
res.dpi() // 96
res.dpcm() // 37.79527559055118
```

Here are some great [resolution takeaways](http://ryanve.com/lab/resolution/) from Ryan Van Etten, the plugin's author:

- 2 unit sets exist and differ at a fixed scale: device units and CSS units.
- Resolution is calculated as the number of dots that can fit along a particular CSS length.
- Unit conversion: 1⁢in = 2.54⁢cm = 96⁢px = 72⁢pt
- CSS has relative and absolute lengths. In normal zoom: 1⁢em = 16⁢px
- dppx is equivalent to device-pixel-ratio.
- devicePixelRatio definition differs by platform.
- Media queries can target min-resolution. Use with care for speed.

Here's the source code for res, as of today:

```
!function(root, name, make) {
  if (typeof module != 'undefined' && module.exports) module.exports = make()
  else root[name] = make()
}(this, 'res', function() {

  var one = {dpi: 96, dpcm: 96 / 2.54}

  function ie() {
    return Math.sqrt(screen.deviceXDPI * screen.deviceYDPI) / one.dpi
  }

  function dppx() {
    // devicePixelRatio: Webkit (Chrome/Android/Safari), Opera (Presto 2.8+), FF 18+
    return typeof window == 'undefined' ? 0 : +window.devicePixelRatio || ie() || 0
  }

  function dpcm() {
    return dppx() * one.dpcm
  }

  function dpi() {
    return dppx() * one.dpi
  }

  return {'dppx': dppx, 'dpi': dpi, 'dpcm': dpcm}
});
```

Answer (score 3):

if you mean browser resolution then

**window.innerWidth** gives you the browser resolution

you can test with http://howbigismybrowser.com/
try changing your screen resolution by zoom in / out browser and check resolution size with http://howbigismybrowser.com/
[image]
Window.innerWidth should be same as screen resolution width

Answer (score 1):

Easy steps to find screen resolution is:

- Copy

```js
`My screen resolution is: ${window.screen.width} * ${window.screen.height}`
```

- paste in browser console
- hit enter

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers