# Running different JavaScript at different screen resolutions

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I want some jQuery functions for a dropdown menu to run only if the the screen size is under 768px and a different dropdown menu function to run if it is above that value. How would I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect the screen resolution with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242086/how-to-detect-the-screen-resolution-with-javascript)

Comment: Window size is far more important than a screen resolution.

Answer (score 8):

You can get the size of the window (screen size is mostly irrelevant, you care about the actual space you have for rendering) using the `.height()` and `.width()` methods:

```
if( $(window).width() > 768 ) {
    // Large menu
} else {
    // Small menu
}
```

Comment: Just for reference, a non-jQuery solution pulled from the [adapt.js](http://adapt.960.gs/) code: `var width = this.innerWidth || this.document.documentElement.clientWidth || this.document.body.clientWidth || 0;`

Comment: That works! One last question is how to I get this to update on resize?

Comment: Don't worry found the resize event :P Silly me.

Answer (score 1):

In your ready function, you could test screen height and width like this :

```
if (screen.width<=768) 
{
//Do this
}
else
```