# How to display user's monitor resolution even on resize?

Tags: javascript, html, screen-resolution, screen-size

I was wondering if there was a way to show a user's screen information that updates when the user resizes their screen. I've seen javascript that just shows the user's screen but doesn't update in real time. Any one know the script for this? Thanks!

Comment: So, you simply want your updating-code (the code that renders the 'screen information block') to also be hooked to `window.onresize`?

Comment: The users monitor resolution will never change even on resize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two thoughts:

1. <s>The `resize` event on `window`, but I suspect the browser won't fire on the screen-size change (might do, though, I suppose). If it doesn't the user will probably resize the window after resizing the screen...</s> Chrome, at least, doesn't fire `resize` when the screen resolution changes but the browser window size doesn't. Sometimes changing the screen resolution will have the knock-on effect of changing the browser size (e.g., if it needs to be smaller, or if it's docked in some way), but frequently not.
2. If browsers don't reliably fire `resize` (and I suspect they don't), you'll have to poll and check the `screen` object to see if the size changed. Not ideal, but polling once a second or so won't be much overhead.

Here's an example using both methods, plus `window.onfocus` as [GitaarLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588079/gitaarlab) suggested: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/bopel/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";
    var lastSize;

    window.onfocus = window.onresize = checkSize;

    setInterval(checkSize, 1000);

    function checkSize() {
      if (!lastSize || (lastSize.width !== screen.width || lastSize.height !== screen.height)) {
        lastSize = {
          width: screen.width,
          height: screen.height
        };
        display("Screen size is (now) " + lastSize.width + "x" + lastSize.height);
      }
    }

    function display(msg) {
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      p.innerHTML = String(msg);
      document.body.appendChild(p);
    }
  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course, you only need polling if notification on *window* resize and window focus isn't sufficient.

Comment: +1 css-trick is an interesting technique. Why do you suspect some browsers will not fire resize (not confusing it with `load` or `focus`)?

Comment: @GitaarLAB: Because changing the screen resolution doesn't usually resize the browser window. Since the browser window size doesn't change, I don't know that browsers fire `resize`. As I say, though, the user will probably resize after a screen resize anyway...

Comment: Deal, I fully understand. So.. what about adding `onfocus` into the mix? I assume the user must unfocused the browser in order to change the resolution, then focus back to the browser to continue browsing? I'm looking at `window.screen.availHeight and window.screen.availWidth`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Wouldn't using the [screen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.screen) object be better?

Comment: @KyleNeedham: Does the screen object have an *event* that it raises when values change? Obviously we'd be using `screen` to find out what the current values are, but... OMG, I'm so stupid. If we're going to poll **anyway**... Thanks for that, here I was trying to make the CSS version work and *using* `screen` in the process. Yikes.

Comment: `window.onresize` AND `window.onfocus` would *not* require polling (interval). Or did I miss something? Extra note: according to a comment to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2242100/588079), `screen.availHeight` and `screen.availWidth` don't take `zoom` into account. Might have a peek at how jQuery's `$(window).width()` and `height()` solve that.

Comment: @GitaarLAB: `onfocus` would only happen...on focus. If that's good enough for the OP, great (and I should have added `onfocus` to my example; will do that now). The OP has been really vague about the use case, so...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Unfortunately not, polling using `window` looks like the most reliable way.

Comment: Hmm. I wonder.. what about (mobile) devices that change resolution when the user flips the screen 90 degrees? There wouldn't be a `focus` event (due to the user focusing to another window to change resolution) *BUT would they fire onresize*?. Or would those devices have some special property that fires an event if the screen is tilted 90 degrees? IF NOT, then we might after-all be back at polling `:(` *OR..* just poll when we have detected a mobile device (again possibly by using css). Food for thought/research.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be saving this!

Answer (score 1):

How about binding a function to `window.onresize`?

```
window.onresize = function (e) {
  console.log("Dimensions: " + e.target.outerWidth + "x" + e.target.outerHeight);
};
```

Comment: What about IE's `window.event`? And cross-browser support?

Comment: I thought (though am currently searching for confirmation) that onresize is cross-browser compliant. If not, your best shot would be `window.addEventListener('resize', fn);`

Comment: `onresize` will work on any browser (and blow away any previous handler attached to it), yes. But `resize` doesn't fire (at least not in Chrome) when the screen size changes but the browser window size doesn't.

Comment: Right. Possibly jumped to a simple solution without considering "external forces".