# Adapt scrollTop to work with different resolutions

Tags: javascript, jquery, screen-resolution

This is what I use to make 2 divs "unwrap" while scrolling:

**CSS**

```
.entry { 
    height: 40px;    
}
.entry.expanded { 
    height:600px;        
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
 $($('.entry').get(0)).addClass('expanded');
 $(window).on('scroll', function (e) {
     var x = $(window).scrollTop();
     if (x > 820) {
         $($('.entry').get(1)).addClass('expanded');
     }
     if (x > 1525) {
         $($('.entry').get(2)).addClass('expanded');
     }
 });
```

It works perfectly fine on my `1920x1080p` screen but it doesn't on a friend's `1920x1200px` because there aren't `820px` to scroll..

How can I solve this to work with every resolution? I tried with this, but unfortunately nothing happens:

```
 $($('.entry').get(0)).addClass('expanded');
 $(window).on('scroll', function (e) {
 var availableScroll = $(document).height() - $window.height();
     var x = $(window).scrollTop();
     if (x > 820 || x  == availableScroll) {
         $($('.entry').get(1)).addClass('expanded');
     }
     if (x > 1525 || x  == availableScroll) {
         $($('.entry').get(2)).addClass('expanded');
     }
 });
```

Is there a fancy method, that maybe calculates the pixels from the bottom or some method relative to the vertical res?

**[Here](http://luca-longobardi.com/suoni-test.html)**'s the webpage with the code live (you can see the 2 divs unwrapping when scrolling).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242086/how-to-detect-the-screen-resolution-with-javascript does this help?

Comment: Mmmh, he also talks about $(window).height()

Comment: `$(window).availHeight` sounds like what you're looking for

Comment: I tried replacing `$window.height()` with `$(window).availHeight` but it's still the same. On iPhone in portrait mode there's no scrolling on default page load but still the function is not triggered (i.e. the divs don't have the class added).

Comment: Why are you subtracting `$(document).height() - $window.height()`, those are usually the same. Also, I would caution against the `==` operator here. If the scroll is off by even .0001 it will resolve as false. Maybe try `abs(x - availableScroll) < 10` or any other arbitrarily small difference.

Comment: So, you mean `var availableScroll = abs(x - availableScroll) < 10;` and then still `x > 820 || x  == availableScroll`?

Comment: No luck.. :(
http://luca-longobardi.com/suoni-test3.html

Comment: No, `var availableScroll = $(document).height() - $(window).height();`, `var x = $(window).scrollTop();` and `x > 820 || abs(x - availableScroll) < 10`

Comment: Also, `$window` should be `$(window)`

Comment: Updated the code here, but nothing changed http://luca-longobardi.com/suoni-test3.html

Comment: Ah, switch `abs` to `Math.abs`

Comment: Yes!!! Now it works!! Last thing: now on iPhone portrait mode, the event fires immediately when I scroll. But shouldn't it be fired by default? All the page is displayed on screen, there's no space to scroll

Comment: No, because the block is inside `$(window).on('scroll', ...`. Look at my answer for how to get around this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, avoid the `==` for scrolling because if the scroll is off by even .0001 it will resolve as false. Also replace `$window` with `$(window)`.

```
 $($('.entry').get(0)).addClass('expanded');
 $(window).on('scroll', function (e) {
 var availableScroll = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
     var x = $(window).scrollTop();
     if (x > 820 || Math.abs(x - availableScroll) < 10) {
         $($('.entry').get(1)).addClass('expanded');
     }
     if (x > 1525 || Math.abs(x - availableScroll) < 10) {
         $($('.entry').get(2)).addClass('expanded');
     }
 });
```

Also, if you want to execute code when the page first loads, use the `$(document).ready(handler)` pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Your former functions seems to working fine. I am testing it as MacBook Pro. However, at sometime it seems it is not fired at JQuery. What you can do is you can wait for few milliseconds to check if the scroll is finished. If scroll is finished then you can simply check the value of scroll.

**Option 1**:

[jQuery debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) is a nice one for problems like this. [jsFidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/hYsRh/4/)

So your modified code will be (you need to use debounce)

```
$(window).scroll($.debounce( 250, true, function(){
    console.log("Still scrolling");
}));
$(window).scroll($.debounce( 250, function(){
     var x = $(window).scrollTop();
     console.log("Scrolling finished");
     if (x > 820) {
         $($('.entry').get(1)).addClass('expanded');
     }
     if (x > 1525) {
         $($('.entry').get(2)).addClass('expanded');
     }
}));
```

**Option 2:**

There may be a chance you don't like use JQuery Debounce then you can native approach with timer function. See the code below and you can adjust the timer duration as per your needs.

It is simply waiting for scroll event to be finished and wait for certain milliseconds before it scroll event recalled. If scroll refires then it simply clear the timer and start waiting again. If timer is finished then it executes the method you have stated.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    var timerDuration = 250; // In milliseconds
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
        // do something
         var x = $(window).scrollTop();
     console.log("Scrolling finished");
     if (x > 820) {
         $($('.entry').get(1)).addClass('expanded');
     }
     if (x > 1525) {
         $($('.entry').get(2)).addClass('expanded');
     }
    }, timerDuration));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. :-) I'm trying your second function here http://luca-longobardi.com/suoni-test4.html, on iPhone 5 portrait there's no scrolling space on page load but .entry divs don't have the class added..

Comment: Try printing the value of x in HTML element with fixed position. That will may help in debugging the problem.

Comment: With the full page scroll the value of x is only 805 and your event fires up at 820 :)

Comment: If you check the top value of top of performance div it is nearby 750. Why are firing event at 820? 

$('#performance').position()

Comment: That's true but it's not related to what happens if all the page is displayed on screen and there's no space to scroll