# JS "@media" device resolution change property of js command

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm doing responsivity on my website in JS. How can I change this (normal resolution):

```
$(".card1_content_arrow").click(function () {
    $(".card1_content").css('margin-left', '-45%');
});
```

Into this, when media width is <860px (in css @media all and (max-width: 860px)):

```
$(".card1_content_arrow").click(function () {
    $(".card1_content").css('margin-left', '-100%');
});
```

When I click on `.card1_content_arrow` on big resolution, then `margin-left` will be changed to `-45%'`, but if I will change the resolution to 860px (and less) I want, that when I click on same `.card1_content_arrow`, then `margin-left` will be changed to `-100%`.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect the screen resolution as described on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242086/how-to-detect-the-screen-resolution-with-javascript).

```
$(".card1_content_arrow").click(function () {
    var margin = "-45%";

    if (window.screen.availWidth < 860) {
        margin = "-100%";
    }

    $(".card1_content").css('margin-left', margin);
});
```

I would suggest using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) instead by specifying another class to control the margin.

```
.yourClass {
    margin-left: -45%;
}

@media (max-width: 859px) {
    .yourClass {
        margin-left: -100%;
    }
}
```

You can just add the class into your element and let the browser do the checking.

```
$(".card1_content_arrow").click(function () {
    $(".card1_content").addClass('yourClass');
});
```

Comment: Thank you! :) I did 1st option, but i can see that "css" option would works too! Have a nice day!