# Wrong display resolution in browsers on mobiles

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, mobile-safari

```
document.write('Display size: <b>' + window.screen.width + '×' + window.screen.height + ' px.</b><br>');
document.write('Browser size: <b>' + window.innerWidth + '×' + window.innerHeight + ' px.</b><br>');
document.write('Avail size: <b>' + window.screen.availWidth + '×' + window.screen.availHeight + ' px.</b><br>');
```

On some devices it shows correct resolution, but on some others not. Why it lower than actual resolution in some cases?

Desktop - all fine.

Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 shows 1280*800, correct.

Samsung A5(2017) shows 640*360, but actual resolution is 1920*1080.

iPad 4 shows 1024*768, but actual resolution is 2048*1536.

iPhone 5 SE shows 568*320, but actual resolution is 1136*640.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2242100/4591364

Comment: Oh, thank you! I'll flag my question as duplicate.