# Save JS screen width height to an txt file

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to save on an post action request the Users screen width and height to an .txt file on my hoster?

I have an post action button where redirect to an `post.php` file like this:

```
<?php

header("Location: /dashboard");
$file = fopen("test.txt","a");
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
$browser = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];

foreach($_POST as $variable => $value){
    fwrite($file, $variable);
    fwrite($file, "=");
    fwrite($file, $value);
    fwrite($file, "\r\n");
}
fwrite($file,$ip."\r\n");
fwrite($file,$hostname."\r\n");
fwrite($file,$browser);

fwrite($file, "\r\n");
fclose($file);

exit;
?>
```

I know that i can save the screen `width` and `height` only with JS not php.

Theres any js code that i can add to my html file and connect it with my `post.php` file and save it also in my `test.txt` file?

Thanks

Comment: you can get it with JS and post it to your script. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242086/how-to-detect-the-screen-resolution-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can use JS to calculate the height and Width and send it to the server using Ajax and 
their you can save it to txt file.

```
window.innerHeight
window.innerWidth
```

JS file, Add Ajax code to JS file (Include jQuery for Ajax.)

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "php/save.php",
  data:  {height : window.innerHeight, width: window.innerWidth}
});
```

Now , as your PHP already have code to save $_POST variables , 
there is no need to modify anything in the PHP file

```
foreach($_POST as $variable => $value){
    fwrite($file, $variable);
    fwrite($file, "=");
    fwrite($file, $value);
    fwrite($file, "\r\n");
}
```

this code will automatically make 2 entries for height & width in file.

Comment: First to Mysql DB and then to file?

Comment: No need to send it to SQL db .. Just save it to file.

Answer (score 1):

Using Easy way with creating

> Function + Ajax.

Client

```
function heightAndWidth() {

 var result = {
  height: window.innerHeight,
  width: window.innerWidth
}  

 return result

};
```

Ajax Request/Post

```
$.ajax({type: "POST", url: "php/save.php", data: heightAndWidth() })
```