# How to change window.scrollY listener based on screen size React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a useEffect hook that makes text fade in on scroll to its route. It works great on my screen, a 27 inch MAC, but when i use a small screen I am not quite sure how to change the useEffect to listen to different screen sizes.

```
//these are my two useEffect hooks to make the different texts appear.

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
   
      const show = window.scrollY > 1200;

      if (show) {
        setName("nameAppear");
      } else {
        setName("name");
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {

      const handleScroll = () => {
        const show = window.scrollY > 1100;
        if (show) {
          setText("textAppear")
        } else {
          setText("text")
        }
      };
      document.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
      };


  }, [])
```

This is the entire component.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";


const aboutMeStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({


  name: {
    opacity: "0",
    position: "relative",
    transition: "1s",
    textAlign: "center",
    top: "40%"
  
  },

  nameAppear: {
    opacity: "1",
    position: "relative",
    textAlign: "center",
    transition: "1s",
    top: "40%",
    fontSize: "50px"
  },

  text: {
    fontSize: "20px",
    position: "relative",
    textAlign: "center",
    top: "40%",
    opacity: "0",
    transition: "3s"
  },

  textAppear: {
    fontSize: "20px",
    position: "relative",
    textAlign: "center",
    top: "40%",
    opacity: "1",
    transition: "3s"
  },

  div: {


    height: "1300px",
    top: "80%",
    [theme.breakpoints.down('lg')]: {
      height: "1000px",
      
    },
  },







}));

export default function AboutMe() {
  const classes = aboutMeStyles();

  //set state for fade in and out

  const [name, setName] = useState("name");
  const [text, setText] = useState("text")

  const nameRef = useRef();
  const textRef = useRef()

  nameRef.current = name
  textRef.current = text

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
   
      const show = window.scrollY > 1200;

      if (show) {
        setName("nameAppear");
      } else {
        setName("name");
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {

      const handleScroll = () => {
        const show = window.scrollY > 1100;
        if (show) {
          setText("textAppear")
        } else {
          setText("text")
        }
      };
      document.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
      };


  }, [])
  return (
    <>
     <div id = "AboutMe" className = {classes.div}>
      <Typography className={classes[nameRef.current]}>HI I'M WILLIAM</Typography>
      <br></br>
      <Typography className={classes[textRef.current]}>A full stack engineer with a focus</Typography>
      <Typography className={classes[textRef.current]}>on front end development</Typography>
      <br></br>
      <Typography className={classes[textRef.current]}>Proficient in React.JS, Redux, MERN stack,</Typography>
      <Typography className={classes[textRef.current]}>Node.JS, Javascript, HTML, and CSS.</Typography>
      
    </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

I have decided to move things closer when the screen gets smaller, so my routes still work correctly and there isn't so much white space. Means I need to changed this section based on screensize

```
      const show = window.scrollY > 1200;

      if (show) {
        setName("nameAppear");
      } else {
        setName("name");
      }
    };
```

I have tried adding conditionals and simply did not work, but I am not sure I was doing it correctly.

Any guidance would be appreciated!!

Thank you in advance

Comment: It seems you need to detect the screen size. Have you seen this: [how to detect the screen resolution with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242086/how-to-detect-the-screen-resolution-with-javascript)

Comment: I tried that as well. It would force me to make a lot of conditionals based on screen size and didn't really work for me. The answer I accepted worked perfectly

Comment: As it turns out, you only needed to make the change based on window height, not screensize. Maybe you could edit your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't hard code 1200. You can use window's available height

```
const show = window.scrollY > window.innerHeight;
```

Or if you want your labels to appear when you scroll down at 90% of the screen

```
const show = window.scrollY > window.innerHeight * 0.9; // you can adjust this value
```

Comment: Your second suggestion was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so very much! I had tried your first suggestion but it didn't quite work how I wanted. I did innerHeight * 0.5 and it works on all screens now.