# checking for user's screen resolution

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, bootstrap-5

I'm learning to create a website and I'm trying to make it look slightly different depending on the viewer's screen resolution. Maybe find out if they're viewing the website on a phone so that I can change the layout of the website to a vertical layout or if they're using a laptop and change the layout of the website to a horizontal layout. Perhaps if the ratio of the vertical resolution over the horizontal resolution becomes greater than a certain limit then the website changes its layout?
Any suggestions on how I can do that or other ways to make the website look different based on the screen that it is being viewed on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is multiple ways to do that.

The easieast Media Query: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

The next by JS:
[How to detect a mobile device using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/how-to-detect-a-mobile-device-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) for this:

```css
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .root {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="root">Hi, i am root</div>
```

---

Or you can use javascript's [Window: resize event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) for this task like this:

```js
addEventListener('resize', (event) => {
  if (window.height > 768)
    console.log("You are on desktop")

  else
    console.log("You are on tablet/mobile")
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2r8p01jn/)

Answer (score 2):

you can use a media query inside your css files to adjust styles according to the screens resolution. An example would look like this:

```
// css.file
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff
  }
}
```

you can find more info about this topic in the mozilla webdocs here or in the links mentioned in the other answer:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSMediaRule

In plain javascript you can do something like mentioned in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2242100/11895459