# Website Appears Different on Different Phones

Tags: html, css

I have been struggling to standardize the look of my website on different phones and am looking for some help. The website is [www.fpphotos.store](http://www.fpphotos.store). I have overflow-x:auto; for the table with the images and the images are CSS styled to width 100% and max width 400px. However, on the iPhone 13 this does not seem to work. Top photo is 15 and the bottom photo is the iPhone 13.

[image]
[image]

I tried overflow-x: auto; and making the CSS style of images width: 100% and max-width: 400px;
It works beautifully on the iPhone 15 but not on the iPhone 13.

```css
p.tnc {
  text-align: center;
  color: lightcyan;
  background-color: #684c00;
  padding: 3ch;
  margin-top: 0cap;
  font-size: large;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

h1 {
  text-align: left;
  color: lightcyan;
  background-color: #684c00;
  padding: 1ch;
  margin: 0cap;
  font-size: x-large;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font: bold;
  color: lightcyan;
  background-color: #684c00;
  padding: 1ch;
  margin: 0cap;
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

p {
  color: black;
  font-size: medium;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.info {
  text-align: left;
  color: lightcyan;
  background-color: #684c00;
  padding: 3ch;
  margin-bottom: 0cap;
  font-size: medium;
  font-family: Verdana;
  list-style-type: lower-greek;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.contact {
  color: lightcyan;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="icon" href="Original/angrywaspicon.png">
  <link href="fpphotos.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <title>FP PHOTOS</title>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='main.css'>
  <script src='main.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>FP Photos</h1>
  <h2>Photo Options</h2>
  <p class="tnc">ALL IMAGES ARE $6 AND COME IN 6x4 GLOSSY PHOTO PRINTS <br>Free Shipping on All Orders!</p>
  <div style="overflow-x: auto;">
    <table style="width:100%;">
      <tr>
        <td><a href="aw.html"><img style="width="100%" src="/Original/Angry Wasp - Copy.jpg"></td></a>
          <td><a href="gl.html"><img style="width="100%" src="/Original/DSC_0088.JPG"></td></a>
            <td><a href="dl.html"><img style="width="100%" src="/Original/DSC_0211.JPG"></td></a>
              <td><a href="wg.html"><img style="width="100%" src="/Original/DSC_0240.JPG"></td></a>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Angry Wasp</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Grass Lizard</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Diamond Lizard</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Whispering Geckos</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow-x: auto;">
    <table style="width:100%;">
      <tr>
        <td><a href="gddg.html"><img style="width="100%" src="/Original/DSC_0247.JPG"></td></a>
          <td><a href="cu.html"><img style="width="100%" src="/Original/DSC_0260.JPG"></td></a>
            <td><a href="gd.html"><img style="width="100%" src="/Original/DSC_0273.JPG"></td></a>
              <td><a href="r.html"><img style="width="100%" src="/Original/DSC_0279.JPG"></td></a>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Gold Dust Day Gecko</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Climbing Up</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Going Down</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Roaches</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow-x: auto;">
    <table style="width:100%;">
      <tr>
        <td><a href="skm.html"><img style="width="100%" src="/Original/DSC_0609.JPG"></td></a>
          <td><a href="tlfb.html"><img style="width="100%" src="/Original/DSC_0949.JPG"></td></a>
            <td><a href="cjb.html"><img style="width="100%" src="/Original/DSC_1137.JPG"></td></a>
              <td><a href="fjb.html"><img style="width="100%" src="/Original/DSC_1147.JPG"></td></a>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Sky High Macaw</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Two Lil Fruit Bats</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Close June Beetle</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Far June Beetle</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow-x: auto;">
    <table style="width:100%;">
      <tr>
        <td><a href="fm.html"><img style="width="100%" src="/Original/DSC_1184.JPG"></td></a>
          <td><a href="anh.html"><img style="width="100%" src="/Original/Pavement Ants around Honey.JPG"></td></a>
            <td><a href="ptf.html"><img style="width="100%" src="/Original/DSC_0093.JPG"></td></a>
              <td><a href="ffh.html"><img style="width="100%" src="/Original/DSC_0128.JPG"></td></a>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Fighting Mantis</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Ants n' Honey</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Pink Tropical Flower</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Flower from Heaven</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow-x: auto;">
    <table style="width:100%;">
      <tr>
        <td><a href="wyf.html"><img style="width="100%" src="/Original/DSC_0136.JPG"></td></a>
          <td><a href="pof.html"><img style="width="100%" src="/Original/DSC_0140.JPG"></td></a>
            <td><a href="pcf.html"><img style="width="100%" src="/Original/DSC_0146.JPG"></td></a>
              <td><a href="swf.html"><img style="width="100%" src="/Original/DSC_0154.JPG"></td></a>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>White-Yellow Flower</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Purple Orange Flower</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Pine Cone Flower</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Slender White Flower</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow-x: auto;">
    <table style="width:100%;">
      <tr>
        <td><a href="pbf.html"><img style="width="100%" src="/Original/DSC_0190.JPG"></td></a>
          <td><a href="bf.html"><img style="width="100%" src="/Original/DSC_0193.JPG"></td></a>
            <td><a href="bs.html"><img style="width="100%" src="/Original/DSC_0280.JPG"></td></a>
              <td><a href="fbb.html"><img style="width="100%" src="/Original/DSC_0292.JPG"></td></a>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Pink Bottle Flower</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Bananna Flower</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Blue Shaka</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Flower Behind Bars</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow-x: auto;">
    <table style="width:100%;">
      <tr>
        <td><a href="fr.html"><img style="width="100%" src="/Original/DSC_0005.JPG"></td></a>
          <td><a href="fu.html"><img style="width="100%" src="/Original/DSC_0007.JPG"></td></a>
            <td><a href="fp.html"><img style="width="100%" src="/Original/DSC_0009.JPG"></td></a>
              <td><a href="is.html"><img style="width="100%" src="/Original/DSC_0022.JPG"></td></a>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Frozer Rivers</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Frozen Upstream</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Frozen Plant</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Ice Shelf</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <ul class="info">
    <a class="contact" href="mailto:fpphotostore@gmail.com">
      <li>fpphotostore@gmail.com</li>
    </a>
    <a class="contact" href="tel:208-830-8555">
      <li>(208)-971-5260</li>
    </a>
    <a class="contact" href="/sitemap.xml">
      <li>Sitemap</li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You haven't explained the problem. "Doesn't seem to work" isn't helpful. Please revise to explain exactly what we should be looking at.

Comment: Protip: Sprinkling inline styles into your document makes it much harder to work with and maintain. Use your stylesheet for _all_ styling. Create reusable classes for specific styles.

Comment: `style="width="100%"` typo/wrong syntax here, etc

Comment: You should use a code editor with a linter, and learn how to use the browser's development tools. Both would warn you about the syntax errors you made. Remember that browsers tend to do their best to display a website even when the code has errors.

Comment: Another non-answer, but using a `table` for layout in this instance is not good way to go about this. You'd get much better results, IMHO, using `flex` or `grid`. `tables` should be used for actual table data.

Comment: I rewrote the code to include grid, now that I have the photos in the grid, how can I add a caption to the photos inside the grid.

Comment: @JFP without seeing your rewritten code, it would be hard to tell you. You can just put the caption in the same `<div>` as the `img`.

Answer (score -2):

I had a problem like this when trying to go from laptop to PC. I am not sure it will work, but try changing all of the size options to pixels instead of percentages. If that does not work, the issue is most likely screen size, and you can try to make a script for different formats based on screen size.

[How to detect screen size with js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242086/how-to-detect-the-screen-resolution-with-javascript)

From there you can set the whole screen to fit the device, and if needed, change the size of the elements. You can calculate that by taking the size of the elements that work on one phone, and that phone's resolution in pixels, and adjust it on the other device to fit. For example, the iPhone 15 has a screen resolution of 2556 x 1179, and the image size is 100 x 120, divide 120 by 2556(0.046), that's your height(Phone resolution is height x width, and the image is still width x height), and divide 100 by 1179(0.084) that's your width. Now take that ratio(0.046:0.084) and multiply with the resolution of the other device. You said you used an iPhone 13, its resolution is 2532×1170, slightly different from the 15, which may be causing the issue. The new image size should be about 98 x 116(Remember that image height is still width times height, so you must flip them, 2532 * 0.046 is about 98, and 0.084 * 1170 is about 116. You need to round, as sub-pixels are not valid).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome! While using JS is certainly a way to go about this, it's really overkill for a really simple CSS responsive image solution.

Comment: If something else works, I'm all for it, I just know that I had a similar issue, and no other solution worked. Thanks for the feedback though!

Comment: Sure! But honestly, there is no reason to sniff screen size with JS. CSS media queries can handle this, and OPs code overall needs work. That said, I did not downvote this, but if you want to produce a better answer, you should **show** the code, in an example, using a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). As of now, this answer is just a huge paragraph of somewhat unhelpful text.